# copy and then convert pivot table to normal table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

i have below code that copies all the tables and pivot table into a new workbook then converting the pivot tables into a regular table but the result is it adds a new header even if the pasted data already has headers, using `xlNo` and `xlYes` has the same result

**UPDATE SOLVED: a single comma was needed i realized had to use record macro in excel to see the correct code**

**from this `Set ptbl = newWs.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, pasteRange.CurrentRegion, xlNo)`**

**to this `Set ptbl = newWs.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, pasteRange.CurrentRegion, ,xlYes)`**

```
Sub CopyTablesToNewWorkbook()

    Dim tbl As ListObject, ntbl As ListObject
    Dim newWb As Workbook
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim pasteRange As Range
    
    Set newWb = Workbooks.Add
    Set newWs = newWb.Sheets(1)
    
    Set pasteRange = newWs.Range("A1")
    
    For Each tbl In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").ListObjects
        Set copyRange = tbl.Range
        copyRange.Copy pasteRange
        Set pasteRange = pasteRange.Offset(copyRange.Rows.Count + 1, 0)
    Next tbl
    
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    For Each pt In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").PivotTables
        If pt.TableRange1.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            pt.TableRange1.Copy
            pasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                                                      :=False, Transpose:=False
            Dim ptbl As ListObject
            Set ptbl = newWs.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, pasteRange.CurrentRegion, ,xlYes)
            Set pasteRange = pasteRange.Offset(pt.TableRange1.Rows.Count + 1, 0)

        End If
    Next pt
    
    For Each ntbl In newWs.ListObjects
        ntbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium20"
    Next ntbl
    
End Sub
```

current result

[image]

desired result

[image]

Comment: `ws.ListObjects` what is `ws` here?

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks! should have been `Set ptbl = newWs.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, xlYes)` now works but found out it creates a new header even with the `xlYes` , it means the selection has headers already right?